# Get shopping cart details in Magento2

Tags: magento2

I know in Magento 1 you can get the shopping cart details on any page with:

```
$cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote();
foreach ($cart->getAllItems() as $item) {
    $productId = $item->getProduct()->getId();
    $productPrice = $item->getProduct()->getPrice();
}
```

How do I do the same thing in Magento 2?